# Typescript : filter an array to another one

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

i have an array of objects "**inputData**" , which looks like this :

```
[{code:"11" , name= "test1" , state:"active" , flag:"stat"},
{code:"145" , name= "test2" , state:"inactive" , flag:"pass"},
{code1:"785" , name= "test3" , state:"active" , flag:"stat"},
...
]
```

without looping over it , **i want to filter it to obtain** an **ouputData** array , looking like this :

```
[{id:"11" , libelle= "test1"},
{id:"145" , libelle= "test2"},
{id:"785" , libelle= "test3"},
...
]
```

where

**code** **->** **id**

and

**name** **->** **libelle**

**sugesstions ??**

Comment: Why not looping ?

Comment: What have you tried ? Show the code you have written to try to do it by yourself?

Answer (score 3):

You can map your array into another one.

`const outputData = inputData.map(({ code: id, name: libelle }) => ({ id, libelle }))`

Note that I'm using some `es6` features like [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), parameters  [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: I think `map` is part of ES5, not ES6?